# spring data neo4j set @GraphId value

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I want to create node via spring data neo4j,and I want set the node id by myself,so I set the @GraphId field.but the neo4j cannot create the node .howhever,if I don't set the @GraphId field,the neo4j will create the node.
so how to set node id?

Comment: @GraphId  Long id;
create setter and getter
if you manually want to set use setter (if issue persist then use atOverride before setter and getter)
if id is not set then SDN will create else use the id provided by user.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity class, your id parameter should have the type of Long:

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyClass{
  ...
  @Getter
  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  ....
}
```

> Annotation for the field that virtually provides the Id of the graph entity (node or relationship), type of the field should be Long

source :  [official documentation Spring-data-neo4j](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/GraphId.html)